# "Не_конкретно" пишется слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

И вот такой разнобой в ответе отмечается совершенно крайне не конкретно (неконкретно).

Comment: Оба варианта безобразны. Предложение требует правки.

Answer (score 1):

**И вот такой разнобой в ответе отмечается совершенно (крайне) неконкретно.**

1) Наречия степени ***крайне*** и ***совершенно*** усиливают утверждение признака (отсюда следует слитное написание ***неконкретно***), но нужно **выбрать только одно из них.**

2) В Нацкорпусе сочетания ***крайне неконкретно, совершенно неконкретно*** не встречаются. Возможно, это связано с тем, что трудно определить отношение наречий в сочетании ***совершенно неконкретно***.

3) В то же время можно встретить (хотя и не часто) **усилительные конструкции** с этим наречием, в том числе авторского характера:

― Это **слишком неконкретно**. Для чего это вам? [Эдуард Хруцкий. Осень в Сокольниках (1983)]

**Непозволительно неконкретно**, не говоря уже о безнадежной дискредитированности слова «культурология» избытком немотивированных употреблений. [Ольга Балла. Истолкователь пространств // «Знание - сила», 2006]

Answer (score 0):

1. Пишется только слитно. Слова "очень", "крайне" и так далее закрепляют утверждение, в том числе **утверждение** отрицания. Благодаря этому пишется слитно: "очень нехороший", "крайне неграмоный".
2. Есть, кстати, такие слова, которые напротив закрепляют **отрицание** утверждения: вовсе, отнюдь, далеко, ничуть и т. д. А в таком случае "не" пишется раздельно: вовсе не глухо, далеко не плохо.